# SQL query not returning correct output with NOT IN

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table **`TAB`** wth the following sample content :

| Person_number | Eff_start_date | department |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 10 | 01-jun-2022 | xyz |
| 18 | 15-may-2022 | Instant |
| 19 | 14-may-2022 | Hudson |
| 20 | 03-May-2022 | xyz |
| 28 | 15-may-2022 | Replay |
| 29 | 14-may-2022 | Bay |
| 30 | 03-May-2022 | Fifty BG |

I want to create the query to fetch output:

- if the **`eff_start_Date`** is ***`< 15-may-2022`*** and department is not in ***`Instant`***
- ***`Hudson`*** departments should also not be included in the output.

Is this query valid ?

```
SELECT person_number, eff_start_date, department AS dept_name
  FROM tab
 WHERE tab.dept_name NOT IN ('Hudson')
    OR(tab.dept_name NOT IN 'Instant' AND
       TO_CHAR(eff_start_date, 'YYYY/MM/DD') < '2022/05/15')
```

If I run this query, I do not get the expected output which would be xyz, Replay, Bay, Fifty BG.

Comment: If you are checking for single value, why do you need IN? Equality check will do

Comment: Also, would suggest using TO_DATE on your filter date in the condition, rather than converting date column to char for comparison

Comment: Why do you expect to get "Replay" in the output? The department not in `Instant` condition is true but the `eff_start_date` < 2022-05-15 is not true. Should the output not be the rows with people numbers `20`, `29`, and `30`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could start by eliminating the cases whenever department is neither equals to ***`Instant`***, nor to ***`Hudson`***. But add a **`CASE WHEN ... THEN`** expression as needing an extra condition for the case when department equals to ***`Instant`*** such as

```
SELECT *
  FROM tab
 WHERE (department NOT IN ('Instant' ,'Hudson'))
    OR CASE
         WHEN department = 'Instant' THEN
          eff_start_date
       END >= date'2022-05-15'
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=e619207c870df247e96546667ceaeca6)</kbd>

Comment: The OP's requirement is "if the `eff_start_Date` is < 15-may-2022 and department is not in `Instant`. `Hudson` departments should also not be included in the output. " This returns rows that are >= 2022-05-15.

Answer (score 1):

You can use date as it is in your WHERE clause in the query.
Modify your query, like so,

```
select PERSON_NUMBER,
EFF_START_DATE,
DEPARTMENT DEPT_NAME
FROM TBL
WHERE  TBL.DEPT_NAME <> 'Hudson'
or ( TBL.DEPT_NAME <> 'Instant'
    AND   EFF_START_DATE < TO_DATE('2022/05/15','YYYY/MM/DD')
    )
```

Comment: According to the description in the question, the two conditions must be checked using AND, not OR.

Comment: Please read carefully the description in the question: "I do not get the expected output which would be xyz, Replay, Bay, Fifty BG." -> The dept_name "Hudson" should not appear in the result set. But when using OR instead of AND, it will appear because it meets the second condition of the OR.

Comment: The question itself has ambiguity, the OP would need to apply AND or OR as per his requirement and choose, based on his reputation score, I think he knows that much.

Comment: Unfortunately this query returns every row as output [Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=fc4663ba3cb9dcda22fa7f74cd6f9031)

Answer (score 0):

Your Combination of logic should be something like this

```
SELECT
    PERSON_NUMBER,
    EFF_START_DATE,
    DEPARTMENT DEPT_NAME
FROM 
    TBL
WHERE  
    TBL.DEPT_NAME <> 'Hudson'
    AND (TBL.DEPT_NAME <> 'Instant'
        AND EFF_START_DATE < TO_DATE('2022/05/15','YYYY/MM/DD'))
```

Don't remove any of the brackets

Comment: Sorry but, this query yields wrong result ( [Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=cad282ebb6bb437d1a8a21123dd3facd) )

Comment: @BarbarosÖzhan The requirement is "if the `eff_start_Date` is < 15-may-2022 and department is not in `Instant`. `Hudson` departments should also not be included in the output." This may not match the OP's desired output but it does match their stated requirements.